# What are the idioms used in modeling?

Tags: modeling, idioms, alloy

On page 195 of the book Software Abstractions it says:

> Alloy doesn’t have a fixed idiom for models, so you are free to use
>   whatever idiom works best for the model at hand.

The book gives a great example of using an "event idiom" to model hotel operations, which involve events such as check-in, checkout, and room entry.

I believe that there is an "object-oriented idiom," right? What other idioms are used in modeling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think "object-oriented" is an Alloy idiom in its own right, because all Alloy models have a bit of that object-oriented flavor (sigs look like classes, sigs can have fields, and you can even append facts to sigs where you can use the `this` keyword).

Other than the event idiom, I don't know of any other well-established Alloy idiom with an instantly recognizable name.

Comment: Thank you Aleksandar! Do you mean to say: ... I don't know of any other ... (missing the word "don't")